# Creating new columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have several columns (literally) named A1, A2, A3, ... A50 in a data.table in R. Unfortunately, columns in my table are not arranged alphabetically.

I want to create a new column named sumA, which will contain A1 + A2 + ... + A50.

What's a simple (and not tedious) way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `dt[, sumA := Reduce("+", .SD)]` assuming that the columns are A1:A50

Comment: What if I have other columns B1, B2, ... B50 that I don't want to include in sumA?

Comment: I posted a solution with that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option with `Reduce` and `+`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, sumA := Reduce("+", .SD)]
```

If there are other columns i.e. columns other than 'A1:A50' in the dataset, use the `.SDcols` to specify the columns to select

```
dt[, sumA := Reduce("+", .SD), .SDcols = paste0("A", 1:50)]
```

Or as @Arun mentioned, if the columns are ordered, then `:` can be used to select the column

```
dt[, sumA := Reduce("+", .SD), .SDcols = A1:A50]
```

Comment: For interactive use, you can also specify `startcol:endcol`.. i.e., `.SDcols=A1:A50` (assuming they're the start and end cols).

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfect. If any newbies are wondering what Reduce does in R, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545688/i-dont-understand-the-function-reduce-in-r

Comment: @wwl One thing to watch out for with this approach is the treatment of missing values. The `sum` function has an `na.rm` option, while `+` does not (so you can't "ignore" `NA`s). The linked question shows a way of addressing that.