# Pythonic reduce with accumlation and arbitrary lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, reduce, accumulate

What would be the Pythonic way of performing a reduce with accumulation?

For example, take `R`'s [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html). Given a list and an arbitrary lambda function it allows for yielding a vector of accumulated results instead of only the final result by setting `accumulate=T`. An example for this with a simple multiplication as lambda function would be (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28545991/6229919)):

```
Reduce(`*`, x=list(5,4,3,2), accumulate=TRUE)
# [1]   5  20  60 120
```

It is important that an arbitrary lambda function (like `lambda x, y: ...`) can be used, so solutions that allow for e.g. only using a sum, multiplication, or else won't do the trick. I was not able to come up with a Pythonic solution to do this with e.g. Python's [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html) or [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html), but there might be a way. And though there are numerous other questions and answers on reduce and specially accumulation with Python I did not spot a generic answer so far.

A non-Pythonic example using a loop for performing a accumulated reduce with an arbitrary lambda function could look like this:

```
# the source list
l = [0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9]
# the lambda function for aggregation can be arbitrary
# this one is just made up for the example
func = lambda x, y: x * 0.65 + y * 0.35 

# the accumulated reduce:
# a) the target list with initializer value hardcoded
l2 = [l[0]]
# b) the loop
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    l2 += [func(
            l2[i-1],    # last value in l2
            l[i]        # new value from l   
            )]
```

So: how would you do a reduce with accumulation and arbitrary lambda function in a Pythonic way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3 (introduced in 3.2, ability to pass the function added in 3.3) this is already implemented, in [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). Just use it like this:

```
from itertools import accumulate
list(accumulate([5, 4, 3, 2], lambda a, b: a*b))
# [5, 20, 60, 120]
```

---

If you are using an earlier Python version, or want to implement it yourself, and you really want any arbitrary `lambda` (that takes two arguments) to work, then you could use the generator which is given in the documentation of the above:

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        total = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

The usage is exactly the same as above.

---

If you are using `numpy`, then there exists a faster solution, at least for all `numpy.ufunc`s. These include basically the same functions that the standard library module `math` provides, and then some. You can find a complete list [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#available-ufuncs).

Every `numpy.ufunc` has the [`accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) method, so you can just do:

```
import numpy as np
np.multiply.accumulate([5, 4, 3, 2])
# array([  5,  20,  60, 120])
```